# Java - Wait for Runnable to finish

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my app, I have the following code running on a background thread:

```
MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
runOnUiThread(myRunnable);

synchronized (myRunnable) {
    myRunnable.wait();
}

//rest of my code
```

And MyRunnable looks like this:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {

        //do some tasks

        synchronized (this) {
            this.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

I want the background thread to continue after myRunnable has finished executing. I've been told that the above code should take care of that, but there are two things I don't understand:

1. If the background thread acquires myRunnable's lock, then shouldn't myRunnable block before it's able to call notify() ?
2. How do I know that notify() isn't called before wait() ?

Comment: You may want to consider implementing this via [ListenableFuture#addListener](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html#addListener(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor)) (for Java7) or [CompletableFuture#thenRunAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenRunAsync-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) (for Java8) as more modern alternatives to `wait`/`notify`

Comment: Why don't you use ```Thread.join()```?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `myRunnable.wait()` will release the lock of `myRunnable` and wait notify
2. we always add a check before wait.

   ```
   //synchronized wait block
   while(myRunnable.needWait){
       myRunnable.wait();
   }

   //synchronized notify block
   this.needWait = false;
   myRunnable.notify();
   ```

Comment: @gediminas-rimsa should be the marked solution.

Comment: @LucBoissaye `If the background thread acquires myRunnable's lock, then shouldn't myRunnable block before it's able to call notify() ?

How do I know that notify() isn't called before wait() ?`

Answer (score 9):

You could also use JDK's standard [RunnableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RunnableFuture.html) like this:

```
RunnableFuture<Void> task = new FutureTask<>(runnable, null);
runOnUiThread(task);
try {
    task.get(); // this will block until Runnable completes
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: this is the cleanest solution imo

Answer (score 0):

1. The lock is released when the wait starts
2. That's a possibility, you can avoid it by putting the `runOnUiThread` within the `synchronized` block too (so that the runnable can't acquire the lock until the other thread is already waiting)

Answer (score 0):

Create an `Object` called `lock`. Then after `runOnUiThread(myRunnable);`, you can call `lock.wait()`. And when your `myRunnable` is finish it's job, call `lock.notify()`. But you must declare `MyRunnable` as inner class, so they can share the `lock` object.